# Underscored foreach variable inside caption not working

Tags: pgfplots, captions, subfloats, foreach, loops

I have the following latex code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\foreach \dataset\nLayers in {donut_1d/15, donut_2d/17, squares_2d/8, spiral_2d/7}
{
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \foreach \etas in {0, 1e-5, 1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1}
        {
            \begin{subfigure}{0.32225\linewidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../TesiMagistrale/PredictionsW2NormReg/pred_\dataset_ResNet_\nLayers_\etas}
            \end{subfigure}%
            \vspace{0.1cm}%
        }
        \caption{\dataset}
    \end{figure}
}

\end{document}
```

but in the caption I get the interpreted variable for `\dataset` so I get the subscript numbers. I want to have the native variable text with the underscore in the caption. Moreover I want it with `\texttt`. I looked at some other questions with underscore and caption but they seem not to help me. They used `\protect` and `\detokenize` but I tried and nothing helped me. I added also the packages I'm using. This is what I get

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Unfortunately, there is necessary context missing from your example; what you are asking may behave differently depending on the document class and relevant packages you are using.  Please expand your example so that potential helpers can compile it to see what you are seeing.  That means, start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `\detokenize\expandafter`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\foreach \dataset\nLayers in {donut_1d/15, donut_2d/17, squares_2d/8, spiral_2d/7}
{
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \foreach \etas in {0, 1e-5, 1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1}
        {
            \begin{subfigure}{0.32225\linewidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../TesiMagistrale/PredictionsW2NormReg/pred_\dataset_ResNet_\nLayers_\etas}
            \end{subfigure}%
            \vspace{0.1cm}%
        }
        \caption{\texttt{\detokenize\expandafter{\dataset}}}
    \end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: Ok but I don't really need texttt in all the caption. Anyway I try this solution.

Comment: Your solution does not work for me. Adding only backslashes throws more errors for me. Moreover I'm working on overleaf.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what your are talking about.

Comment: Try `\detokenize\expandafter`

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks a lot.